# Force a request from HTTPS to HTTP in HttpServlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a link working with

`"https://" and "http://"`

before .

When I use htppservlet to  request from a `"https://"` , 
I want the response return a `"http://"` . 
So the client can view easier.

How can I do ?

Comment: Do you want to *redirect* to the same servlet via HTTP, or do you want to respond with a page that contains HTTP links? Hopefully a browser will not automatically downgrade from HTTPS to HTTP without prompting the user for confirmation.

Comment: *"So the client can view easier."* This is totally beyond me. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The client want to redirect to that link without "https" . So i must change it into "http"

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the code like this:

```
if (request.isSecure()) { // it is HTTPS
    String reqUrl = req.getRequestURL().toString().replaceFirst("https:", "http:");
    String queryString = req.getQueryString();
    if (queryString != null)
        reqUrl += '?' + queryString;
    response.sendRedirect(reqUrl);
}
```

Comment: You can do the replacement less verbosely (though perhaps less readably?), since `getRequestURL()` returns a `StringBuffer`: `String reqUrl = req.getRequestURL().replace(0, 6, "http:").toString();`

Comment: Thank for your help, i solved that problem by editing in  config file "replace into 'http://' "